# Cómo recorrer una lista multinivel en una plantilla de django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Tengo una lista multinivel que paso a la plantilla de django pero no se como recorrerla, porque es anidada, la lista es la siguiente:

`[{'p': 1407836, 'thijo': 2, 'h': [{'p': 1407854, 'thijo': 1, 'h': [{'p': 1407874, 'thijo': 0, 'h': []}]}, {'p': 1407858, 'thijo': 1, 'h': [{'p': 1407876, 'thijo': 0, 'h': []}]}]}]`

y lo que necesito es acceder al valor de cada llave **`p`**. Pero recuerden que necesito recorrerla, pero en la plantilla de django, no en el controlador.

Comment: Con `for` anidados. ¿Puedes mostrar la parte relevante de tu plantilla? Es importante que incluyas en tus preguntas un __[mcve]__ que ayude a comprender tu problema. Te invito a que visites el __[tour]__.

Answer (score 3):

Deberia ser algo como esto.

```
{% for obj in tulista %}
    <tr>
        ID: {{obj.p}}
        {% for ob in obj.h %}
        <tr>
          ID Anidado: {{ob.p}}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```